# Trigger div when hover span

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

Have an issue trying to trigger a div visable when hovering on a span here is how the code is:

```
<ul class="products">
<li>
<a href="somelink">
<img src="some image">  
<div class="overlay"> Some Text</div>
</a>
<span class="somebtn">title</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

The div should be triggered when hovering on the span, Ive tried css and JS but nothing seems to work :(
Here is some css and Js Ive tried at different times.

CSS

```
.overlay {
 display:none;
}
span.someBtn:hover + div.overlay {
display:block !important;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.someBtn').hover(function() {
    $('.overlay').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Classes are case sensitive, please use: `$('.somebtn')`.

Comment: didnt seem to work, I ended up moving the overlay below the span and used css and its working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use css you have switch the position of the span with the div since css has no previous selector

```css
.overlay {
  display:none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
span.somebtn:hover + div.overlay {
  display:block ;
  background: red
}
```

```html
<ul class="products">
  <li>
    <a href="somelink">
      <img src="some image">  
      <span class="somebtn">title</span>
      <div class="overlay"> Some Text</div>
    </a>

  </li>
</ul>
```

But if you want to use jquery you can to this

```js
$(".somebtn").hover(function(){
  $(".overlay").show()
},function (){
  $(".overlay").hide()
})
```

```css
.overlay {
  display:none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="products">
  <li>
    <a href="somelink">
      <img src="some image">  
      <div class="overlay"> Some Text</div>
      <span class="somebtn">title</span>
      
    </a>

  </li>
</ul>
```

You can use pure Javascript too

```js
function mouseIn(){overlay.style.display = "block"}
function mouseOut(){overlay.style.display = "none"}

var overlay,somebtn;

overlay = document.querySelector(".overlay");
somebtn = document.querySelector(".somebtn");

somebtn.addEventListener("mouseenter",mouseIn,false);
somebtn.addEventListener("mouseout",mouseOut,false)
```

```css
.overlay{
  width: 200px; 
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  display: none
}
```

```html
<ul class="products">
  <li>
    <a href="somelink">
      <img src="some image">  
      <div class="overlay"> Some Text</div>
      <span class="somebtn">title</span>
      
    </a>

  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks I moved the overlay div below the span and the css I had worked perfect Thanks you for taking the time to check this out :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are wanting to make it disappear upon moving the mouse away from the span, but I wrote it that way. Check it out:

```
$(".somebtn").hover(function () {
        $(".overlay").show();
    }, function () {
        $(".overlay").hide();
    });
```

If you didn't want it to disappear, just remove the second function.

Comment: I had used JS exactly like that to no avail, moving the div and using css is working now so Im happy, Thanks for the reply though :)